# jQuery: ajax call not received by IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have this simple [ajax call](http://pastebin.com/NavQWvia). It works fine in firefox/chrome, returning number of messages sent in a chat enviroment without response. In IE however, the alert is called but only returns 0. If I set cache to false, it returns 1..

What might cause this? Is there any known issues regarding this operation in IE using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE will be taking the result from the cache. Since your request URL has not been changed IE interprets it to be the same request and will not fetch data from server.

You can set the `cache` property to `false` during the ajax request.

Read more [**jQuery.ajax( settings )**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Hmmm... so how can I do it? :-/

Comment: Like I said, I tried that... then it only returns 1... not the actual data

Comment: I did, in the post. But it works now! I removed the dataType, and it seems to work now! =) Excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
do you have function foobar() {

}
```

or

```
function foobar {

}
```

pretty sure you need the ()

Comment: Nevermind that, just wrote the in the pastebin, not actual part of the code :)